# Trying to create a RetainAll method

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to create a RetainAll method and all after scouring the forums I have found nothing that helps in my specific case. The issue I am having is that when running my program instead of retaining all the elements form a specified list and deleting all others it instead keeps the last element form the initial list.

```
public default boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
    boolean modified=false;
    int index =0;

    for(Object e : this) {
        if(c.contains(e)==true) {
        }
        else if(c.contains(e)==false) {
            index=this.indexOf(e);

            this.remove(index);
            modified = true;
        }
    }

    return modified;
}

public default boolean remove(Object e) {
    if (indexOf(e) >= 0) {
        remove(indexOf(e));
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

I am just not understanding how to remove the last element.

Comment: Don’t use comparisons like `==true` or `==false`. There’s also no reason to create redundant tests like `if(something) { } else if(the opposite of something) {}`, as the opposite is already proven in the `else` statement, but especially not when the first statement is even empty. Just use `if(!c.contains(e)) { your action }`. For the `remove(Object e)` method, don’t evaluate `indexOf(e)` twice; you’ve already shown to know, how to use local variables to hold the result of an evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying the collection as you iterate over it.  That is generally a recipe for unhappiness.

For the standard collections, the safe way is to use an explicit iterator, and use the iterator's 'remove' method to remove the most recently returned entry.

If this is your own collection implementation you should make sure that model works for you too.